# Possible to pass SSRS report parameter through SSIS Task?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, ssis, subscription

I have a SSRS report with a parameter @Client. The SSRS report subscription should be kicked off at the end of an SSIS ETL job for that particular client, but the report is uniform across all clients. For a particular job, I only want to pass the parameter value for ClientA into @client, so I don't want to preset the parameter as Select All at the time of execution.

I already know how to use `exec ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', @EventData='9c9b80e9-72ca-446b-b6b8-27604f72b8fb'` to kickoff the SSRS report subscription via SSIS, but is it possible to pass a parameter into that report subscription  through the ssis script?

Comment: do you have data driven subscription? Data driven subscription will allow you to pass the value into the parameter for ssrs subscriptions at the runtime. Here is a blog which can help you understand how to setup the data driven subscription: http://jackworthen.com/2016/05/06/creating-a-data-driven-subscription-in-sql-server-reporting-services/

Comment: @CuriousKid This is not exactly what I'm looking for. I'd like the value of the parameter to be defined at runtime of the report subscription, but the value changes based on the SSIS package I'm executing the subscription from. I feel like the method above would only work if I had multiple of the same report for subscription, then define the `@Client` parameter separately for each report. Step 3 from the article is what's deviating from my needs. I need the `@client` to be a/b/c,etc but there's no way to dynamic query step 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass a parameter to SSRS report from SSIS package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471821/how-to-pass-a-parameter-to-ssrs-report-from-ssis-package)